# transfer function op amp feedback circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, feedback

Does anyone know how to calculate the transfer function for this circuit if Vref is the input an Vo the output? Thank you [image]

Comment: What are you taking as the input?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. Vref is the input, Vo is the output.

Comment: Are we assuming an ideal op-amp?

Comment: Yes ideal op amp

Comment: Use superposition: [Vref(1+Z2/Z1)+Vout*(-Z2/Z1)]*G=Vout

Comment: Thx. What if a block, let's say H is added in the feedback path?

Comment: Which feedback path?

Comment: Thank you all for your interest. I meant, if H is added to the feedback path going from Vout to Z1(s)

Comment: [Vref(1+Z2/Z1)+Vout*H*(-Z2/Z1)]*G=Vout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transfer function of such a system with feedback can be found using the general formula

Vout/Vin=H(forward)/(1-loop gain).

In you case:

**Vout/Vref=G(s)*(1+Z2/Z1)/[1-G(s)*(-Z2/Z1)*H(s)]**

If H(s) is not existent set H(s)=1.

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean exactly with H(forward)? in your formula: Vout/Vin=H(forward)/(1-loop gain).

Comment: As you can see from the final transfer function formula, H(forward) is the forward gain between input and output without any feedback.

Comment: ok thx, it makes sense